# Let $f$ be a function such that $ \sqrt {x - \sqrt { x + f(x) } } = f(x) , $

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function such that $$ \sqrt {x - \sqrt { x + f(x) } } = f(x) , $$ for $x > 1$. In that domain, $f(x)$ has the form $\frac{a+\sqrt{cx+d}}{b},$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $a,b$ are relatively prime. Find $a+b+c+d.$

Comment: To get a better response you are encouraged to update the question with your own approach to trying to solve the problem and let people know what is exactly the problem(s) you are having.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%9A%281009-%E2%88%9A%281009%2Bf%29%29%3Df) suggests very highly that the solution is $\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{4x-3}}2$. A quick check shows that this works. (1009 was chosen at random.)

Comment: Where did you get this problem, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

Let's write $f$ for $f(x)$.
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+f}}&=f\\
x-\sqrt{x+f}&=f^2\\
\sqrt{x+f}&=-f^2+x\\
x+f&=f^4-2xf^2+x^2\\
0&=f^4-2xf^2-f+x^2-x
\end{align}
This looks like a very ugly equation to solve. We want to factor that somehow (maybe there's some difference of squares in there? I can't see it...) Since we have nothing else to do, let's complete the square on the right. (Why? Well, I'm hoping for a difference of two squares somewhere, so getting a square in there seems like a good start.)
\begin{align}
0&=f^4-2xf^2-f+x^2-x\\
0&=f^4-2xf^2-f+\Big(x-\frac12\Big)^2-\frac14
\end{align}
Let's ignore the $-\frac14$ at the end for just one second, and look at the rest. What do we have here? Well, $f^4-\textit{something}+(x-\frac12)^2$. This is *almost* a square! (Remember that $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$; we have the $a^2$ and $b^2$ in here.)

So, let's try seeing what $(f^2-(x-\frac12))^2$ looks like. (Maybe we'll get lucky and find out that our thing actually *is* a square.)

> \begin{align}
> \Big(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12 \right)\Big)^2&=f^4-2f^2 \left(x-\frac12 \right)+\Big(x-\frac12\Big)^2\\
> &=f^4-2f^2x+f^2+\left(x-\frac12\right)^2
> \end{align}

Drats — that's *almost* what we have. What we have is that thing, but with a $-f$ instead of a $+f^2$. In other words, we have $\textit{that thing}-f^2-f$. Well, let's put it into our equation above anyway:
\begin{align}
0&=f^4-2xf^2-f+\Big(x-\frac12\Big)^2-\frac14\\
&=\left(\left(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12\right)\right)^2-f^2-f \right)-\frac14\\
&=\Big(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12 \right)\Big)^2-f^2-f-\frac14
\end{align}
Woah! We can factor that...
\begin{align}
&=\Big(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12 \right)\Big)^2-\left(f+\tfrac12 \right)^2
\end{align}
And suddenly it's the difference of two squares:
\begin{align}
&=\Big(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12 \right)+\left(f+\tfrac12 \right)\Big)\Big(f^2-\left(x-\tfrac12 \right)-\left(f+\tfrac12 \right)\Big)\\
&=(f^2+f-x+1)(f^2-f-x)
\end{align}

Woohoo! We factored that beast. The end is in sight.

We now split this into two equations: $f^2+f-x+1=0$ and $f^2-f-x=0$. Each give us two possible solutions. After using the quadratic formula, we end up with
$$\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4x-3}}2,\frac{1\pm\sqrt{4x+1}}2$$
Now, we need to test each of these to see which one works. Actually, this isn't too bad — we can just choose a good choice for $x>1$ for each of these (preferably a choice of $x$ that gives us lots of integers) and see if they work. (Why $x>1$? 'Cause that's what the problem says.)

So, let's pick good values of $x$ and plug them into the original equation: $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+f}}=f$.

Working with $x=3$, the first two solutions give me $1=1$ and $\sqrt2=-2$ respectively; working with $x=2$, the last two solutions give me $0=2$ and $1=-1$ respectively. Clearly, only the first one works; thus, the solution is:

$$f=\frac{-1+\sqrt{4x-3}}2$$

EDIT: Technically, they want you to find $a+b+c+d$. So, the answer is $(-1)+(2)+(4)+(-3)=2$.

Comment: (As for where $x=3$ and $x=2$ came from at the very end: I wanted $\sqrt{4x-3}$ and $\sqrt{4x+1}$ to be integers, and those choices of $x$ worked.)

Comment: Technically, I've only proven that $\frac{-1+\sqrt{4x-3}}2$ works in the special case of $x=3$. But, we know that _something_ works, since otherwise they wouldn't give you the problem. Also, you can check that it also works for $x=7$, which can't be a coincidence. And if you're after mathematical rigor, just plug $\frac{-1+\sqrt{4x-3}}2$ into the original equation to see if it works.

Comment: Great job on this. It's very thorough. Even though it is a little colloquial, a lot can be gained from it. Nice solution :)

Comment: "Why $x>1$? 'Cause that's what the problem says." It's because the solution you find is only a true solution when $x\geq 1$. Since $f = \sqrt{\ldots}$ we must have $f\geq 0$ which is only true when $x\geq 1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I always find formal language hard to read. "Never use a long word where a short one will do" and all that. (Not that I'd want this to be too informal. if i didnt spel stuff right or use good gramer this would be a lot harder 2 read.)